# This page can not be displayed error in SharePoint 2013 Central Admin

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I was trying to open CA first time after completion of SharePoint 2013 installation. Getting error like below.

> This page can not displayed.

Any one help me on this.

Comment: more information required i.e what sharepoint version, new install or old farm, accessing CA from server or pc? any errors in the event log

Comment: Control IIS App Pool Status and website, Check services also.

Comment: Hi Waqas Sarwar, Sharepoint 2013 version and accessing CA from server

Comment: Hi Seb, I have checked IIS App pool and website, services every thing is started mode.